# How is a badge "recommended"?

Tags: discussion, badges

While tracking my "Next Badge", I came across the small, green "recommended" tab on the top-right corner of a badge.

- How does Stack Overflow decide its "recommended badge" (The Algorithm) ?
- What is the logic behind the ordering of rest of the badges ?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259390/what-does-most-logical-mean-about-the-next-badge-on-the-profile/259391#259391

Comment: Just make a proposal for it here. It has to pass our critical eyes :P

Answer (score 5):

According to [this answer on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/330614/295232) by @animuson, a Stack Overflow employee:

> It runs through the following logic tree, stopping at the first recommendation that matches:
>
> - Recommend Excavator if Excavator is enabled, user doesn't have Excavator, and user has edit questions and answers privilege.
> - Recommend Custodian if the current site is not a child meta, user doesn't have Custodian, and user has access review queues privilege.
> - Recommend Supporter if user doesn't have Supporter and user has vote up privilege.
> - Recommend Critic if user doesn't have Critic and user has vote down privilege.
> - Recommend most progressed badge that user doesn't currently have and has at least 50% progress already.
> - Recommend Informed if the current site is not a child meta and user doesn't have Informed.
> - Recommend Autobiographer if user doesn't have Autobiographer.
> - Recommend Student if user doesn't have Student.
> - Recommend Teacher if user doesn't have Teacher.
> - Recommend Editor if user doesn't have Editor.
> - Recommend most progressed badge that user doesn't currently have, no progress minimum.
>
> Note that for the two points in the line that look at current badge progress, the progress is stored as an integer, which means that it gets no decimals to increase specificity. So in your example where Illuminator is 66.4% and Legendary is 66.6%, they both appear as just 66% and the sorting defaults to just alphabetically for matching percentages.