# How does Stack Overflow decide the "next badge" field for a user?

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-progress

The last badge I received was the Notable Question badge. I was hoping to see that the next badge for me would be Famous Question, however, Stack Overflow says that my next badge is Organizer.

I am just wondering what algorithm they use to select what the next badge for a user should be.

Comment: (Also, click the wee cogwheel to change the badge.)

Comment: See also [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298953/how-is-a-badge-recommended?rq=1).

Comment: and [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259390/what-does-most-logical-mean-about-the-next-badge-on-the-profile).

Answer (score 5):

The recommended badge is the one you have currently the most progress in, i.e. you're the closest to achieve. Note that some badges cannot be tracked, especially those like [Famous Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/28/famous-question) which depend on a single post. Tracking is only available for badges you must earn through multiple actions.

If you're not satisfied with the default choice, you can click the cogwheel to change to another badge, as @Biffen notes.